# How to display a list of all pages visited during the session

Tags: php

1. Use the page1.`php` and page2, page3 examples in chapter 23 as template. Create a fourth and fifth page participating the session. On each page, show links to all the other pages (it is OK to include a link to the current page).

On each page, display a list of all pages you visited during this session as shown below.
[Pages display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaKfL.jpg)

-You may use the `Superglobal` variable $_SERVER[“`PHP`_SELF”] to access the name of the current page.

-To declare an empty array use syntax: $some_array = [];

-To append to this array: $some_array[] = ‘Appended string’;

- you may use `foreach`() to retrieve the content of the session array

**Please help me on how to display the list of pages as shown in the example above.**

So far I came up with this code to get the display that is shown in the picture but I am getting errors.

```
<?`php`
session_start();
  //      .$_SESSION['`sess`_var'].'<`br` />';
  $array_var = [];
  $array_var[]= 'tom';
  $array_var[]='`alice`';
  $array_var[7] = 'Smith';

  echo $_SERVER['`PHP`_SELF'];

  $_SESSION['name'] = 'Tom Smith<`br`>';
//  echo $_SESSION['name'];

echo '<a `href`="page1.`php`?p1">Page1.`php`</a>';

echo '<a `href`="page2.`php`?p2">Page2.`php`</a>';

echo '<a `href`="page3.`php`?p3">Page3.`php`</a>';

echo '<a `href`="page4.`php`?p4">Page4.`php`</a>';

echo '<a `href`="page5.`php`?p5">Page5.`php`</a>';

$i=0;

if(`isset`($_GET['p1']))

{

$file_array[$i]="page1.`php`";

$i++;

}

if(`isset`($_GET['p2']))

{

$file_array[$i]="page2.`php`";

$i++;

}

if(`isset`($_GET['p3']))

{

$file_array[$i]="page3.`php`";

$i++;

}

if(`isset`($_GET['p4']))

{

$file_array[$i]="page4.`php`";

$i++;

}

if(`isset`($_GET['p5']))

{

$file_array[$i]="page5.`php`";

$i++;

}

echo "The pages you visited are :";
for($i=0;$i<=$file_array[$i];$i++)

{

?>
<`br`/>
<a `href`="page1.`php`">Page 1</a>
<a `href`="page2.`php`">Page 2</a>
<a `href`="page3.`php`">Page 3</a>
<a `href`="page4.`php`">Page 4</a>
<a `href`="page5.`php`">Page 5</a>
```

Comment: Please indent each line of code with four spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the code below

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
array_push($_SESSION['uriHistory'], $uri);
```

This would get the current `uri` of the page and add that to the PHP `SESSION` variable. You can simply add this before all your pages. To get the list of pages visited simply print the `$_SESSION['uriHistory']` variable.

> Needless to say you need to start **session** for the code to run properly.